# What is better: install a package from a package repository or from a DEB archive?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, deb

I can either install a package from a package repository or from a downloaded `.deb` archive:

For example, installing google chrome:

```
# from a package repository
sudo echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y google-chrome-beta && \
sudo apt-get clean && apt-get -y autoremove

# from a .deb archive
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
sudo apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
rm ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

What approach is better/canonical?

Comment: Both will produce same result. The deb file Google Chrome would eventually add Google's PPA in the system to get future updates.

Comment: dl.google.com is a *third-party repository* (or a *non-Ubuntu repository*), not a PPA

Comment: By the way, I see votes to close this as off-topic. I do not understand the reasoning and think it would be good if such votes are explained in the comments.

Comment: The OP has said in other threads that this is a Debian project, not an Ubuntu project.

Comment: @Kulfy I used google chrome package as an example only. It can be replaced by any package that is missing in the official repository

Comment: @user535733, yea, I am running provided command examples in Debian. But they are pretty generic and can be executed on Ubuntu, too. The question is also generic and answers could be applied to the both OSs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it probably does not matter as the deb package will ask you to add the repository. Generally speaking, a repository is better than a deb package, as it is more often updated and dependencies are handled better.